# Run on IIS without publishing (point IIS to project folder)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, iis-8, razor-pages

I have a .NET Core 3.0 Razor pages project. Is it possible for it to run in the local IIS express WITHOUT publishing?

Comment: .NET Core is designed to enforce that publish process, so in general giving up your idea of running without publishing. Visual Studio uses its trick to do so, but you are not supposed to follow it in production environment, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in IIS without publishing, you could follow steps below:

1. Run VS as administrator
2. Open your Razor page project
3. Right-Click project->properties->Debug tab
4. New profile->IIS
5. Launch-> IIS
6. Enter configuration you need for other fields
7. Run with F5